# How to disable background using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have button on HTML page. When I hover on it, I show a div. When I do that I need to disable the background or gray out background except the new div i have opened. When mouse/cursor moves out of this div, everything should come to normal (enable everything) and new div closes.

How do I do this?

Below is the js fiddle.

```
$("#mylink").hover(function() {
        $("#mydiv").show();
    });

    $("#mydiv").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#mydiv").hide();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ashishjmeshram/hhkvar20/

Comment: reproduce it in fiddle ..

Comment: please share some relevant code so that we can help you better. Also provide jsfiddle link with your problem statement code.

Comment: can you share some link or code

Comment: Share the code you have tried, we are not here to work for your requirements my friend , this is issue discussion and technical site

Comment: @yetanothercoder you need to use the modal popup..https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: @yetanothercoder ..look at this i think you want this ..http://jsfiddle.net/hhkvar20/7/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/esutc7nr/)

```
$("#mylink").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
    $("#mydiv").show();
});

$("#mydiv").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#mylink").css('background-color', 'white');
    $("#mydiv").hide();
});
```

EDIT:

If you want a modal overlay you need also a close button because you can't mouseleave the link when it has a div over it:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/esutc7nr/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
        <div>
            <p>Thsi is some test div.</p>
            <button class="md-close">Close me!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="mylink">Hover to show custom div</a>

<div class="md-overlay"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#mylink").hover(function() {
    $(".md-modal").addClass('md-show');
});

$(".md-close").click(function(){
    $(".md-modal").removeClass('md-show');
});
```

Comment: I hope I understood what you need, otherwise please explain more

Comment: I need to make it similar to jquery popups where you open a popup, only popup is visible and rest of the page is disabled and grayed out.

Comment: I can do that, but if I place the overlay you can't "mouseleave" the link/button anymore you need a "close" link to disable the overlay

Answer (score 0):

Check the hover API of jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/hover/, found a simple answer:

```
    $("#mylink").hover(function() {
        $("#mydiv").show();
    }, function(){
        $("#mydiv").hide();
    });
```

Comment: I need to gray out the other portion of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need Lightbox?
Like this one:
https://gist.github.com/b9d9f8ef4482ca0bd352

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can change the body background color when hover the div and make it normal when remove mouse pointer.

```
$("#mylink").hover(function() {
        $("#mydiv").show();
        $('body').css('background-color','grey');
    },function(){
        $("#mydiv").hide();
        $('body').css('background-color','white');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hhkvar20/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a div that spans the entire page and setting it's bg colour to something opaque? Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhkvar20/6/)

```js
 $("#mylink").hover(function() {
   $("#block").show();
   $("#mydiv").show();
 });

 $("#mydiv").mouseleave(function() {
   $("#mydiv").hide();
   $("#block").hide();
 });
```

```css
#block {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
#mydiv {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
#mydiv button {
  z-index: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="mylink">Hover to show custom div</a>

<div id="mydiv">
  <button>This is some test div.</button>
</div>
<div id="block"></div>
```